# How to add disk in zip using DotNetZip

Tags: drive, dotnetzip

I use DotNetZip for creating zips. It has many option but I couldn't find if it is possible to store the disk where the file is located, in the archive. E.g. like the Absolute mode in 7-Zip. As far as I can see I can only do this:

```
zip.AddFile(cFileFull, cPath);
```

When cFileFull is e.g. "c:\temp\SomeFile.txt" and cPath = "c:\temp" opening the zipfile shows

**temp**

while I would like to see
**C**
and then, when I click on C
**temp**

This allows storing the same path/file found on different drives. Is this possible?

Comment: As often I did not receive a reaction, but for future readers here's a workaround: 
var zipEntry=zip.AddFile(cFileFull, cPath);
zipEntry.Comment=cPath.Substring(0,1);

In a program like 7-zip you can see the comment, being the drive letter, and this is then the only difference if I add 2 exactly the same files in the same directory from a different disk.